# How do I clear errno in C#?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, errno

How do I clear `errno` in `.NET` Core?

I can read it easily enough by `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` but there's no obvious way to set it or clear it. Google searches were spectacularly useless.
`Marshal.SetLastError()` doesn't exist.

I can't seem to write down a P/Invoke for `errno`. It's a thread-static native variable.

In case you're wondering why somebody would want to set it, see `man 3 readdir`. The API specifically calls for setting `errno` to `0`before calling it.

This is what the native code would be:

```
errno = 0;
struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir);
if (entry == NULL && errno != 0) {
     /* Handle error */
}
```

So when written as `.NET` code:

```
????
IntPtr entry NativeMethods.readdir(dir);
if (entry == IntPtr.Zero && Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0) {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

If the code where ???? would be is omitted, this gets spurious errors.

I suppose if I get completely stuck I can do something silly like do something that fails with a definite error code and check for that one, but there just aren't that many cases where  we can utterly exclude one specific error that's easily generated.

Comment: GetLastWin32Error *Returns the error code returned by the **last unmanaged function** that was called using platform invoke that has the **SetLastError flag** set.* - Set the DllImportAttribute with SetLastError flag set to true and it will be done

Comment: And here is an example usage on linux platform https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17198 - Do you see the DllImport Attribute? That is how you clear the last errorno. If there is a bug, then you should report it

Comment: @SirRufo: Ouch! Difference between framework/mono and core!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer turns out to be ???? really is nothing only on .NET Core. It behaves differently on .NET Framework and Mono.

Rufo provided a really nice link of https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17198

This is an intentional difference on .NET Core https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/614 that is very badly documented.